# Appending extra sub-domain to currently existing Let's Encrypt SSL certificate created by Certbot

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt, wildcard-subdomain, certbot

I have a domain `xyz.com` and I have created a Let's Encrypt SSL certificates using Cetbot for `xyz.com` and `www.xyz.com` with the following command

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d xyz.com -d www.xyz.com
```

Now if I want to add `blog.xyz.com`, How could I append and not to write all the sub-domains again since say if I have 100 sub-domains it would be right to list all the 100 sub-domains to add a single extra sub-domain.

So the question is:
How could I append to the currently created certificate and not to list all existing sub-domains?

*I am using Nginx, Certbot and all hosted on a DigitalOcean droplet.*

Answer (score 1):

You can expand an existing Certbot certificate by using the `--expand` option.

Have a look at the documentation: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html?highlight=expand

Best regards.

Comment: using --expand option & referring documentation helped me.


my case was initially i had got SSL certificate for existing.com & www.existing.com and later using --expand command added newdomain.com & www.subdomain.com.


certbot command for my case is :

`certbot --expand -d existing.com,www.existing.com,newdomain.com,www.newdomain.com`

documentation link : https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#re-creating-and-updating-existing-certificates

also make sure A records are added for new subdomains in your DNS settings.